# Regular Expression in Java to remove the trailing digits including Hyphen symbol

Tags: java, regex

I’ve lots of 9-digit zip codes like shown below.

```
94107-1532
94107-1532
94107-1535
94107-1511
```

The first part is the first five digits of the zip code which indicates the destination post office or delivery area. The last 4 digits of the nine-digit ZIP Code represents a specific delivery route within that overall delivery area. I wanted to remove the last 4 digits starting including the Hyphen symbol(`-`). I tried the below expression, but no luck!

```
public static String removeRoute(String zipCode) {
    return zipCode.replaceAll("-\\d$", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `asterisk` or `plus sign` right after the `\d` shorthand.

```
zipCode.replaceAll("-\\d+$", "");
```

OR

```
zipCode.replaceAll("-\\d*$", "");
```

The asterisk or star (`*`) tells the engine to attempt to match the preceding token zero or more times and the plus (`+`)tells the engine to attempt to match the preceding token once or more.

Answer (score 2):

`\\d` only matches one digit character.

Use `\\d+` to match multiple or `\\d{4}` to match exactly four

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't even use regex; just use `String#split`:

```
String input = "94107-1532";
String zip = input.split("-")[0];
String poBox = input.split("-")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are matching a hyphen and a single digit at the end of the string.

A bit more precise match would be to capture the first 5 digits in a group and match the hyphen and 4 digits at the end. In the replacement use group 1

```
^(\d{5})-\d{4}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b8LuW9/1)

Or if the pattern can only occur at the end of the string, you can use for example a word boundary

```
\b(\d{5})-\d{4}$
```

Example code

```
public static String removeRoute(String zipCode) {
    return zipCode.replaceAll("^(\\d{5})-\\d{4}$", "$1");
}
```